# MDX code to find last month of current year:dynamic

Tags: ssas, mdx

I want to create a calculation in a cube and try to find out just the last month of current year. I want this last month as a slicer in my `Power BI` report (the cube is connected through Live Connection) so cant create this code in `DAX`.
Please help me to write this in `YYYYMM` format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using USER hierarchy then below example can help

with member measures.t 
as 
(Descendants  ([Date].[Calendar].currentmember,[Date].[Calendar].[Month],SELF).item(
Descendants ([Date].[Calendar].currentmember,[Date].[Calendar].[Month],SELF).count-1).item(0)
,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])

member measures.t1 
as 
Descendants  ([Date].[Calendar].currentmember,[Date].[Calendar].[Month],SELF).item(
Descendants ([Date].[Calendar].currentmember,[Date].[Calendar].[Month],SELF).count-1).item(0).name

SELECT {measures.t ,measures.t1}
ON 0 ,
[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2013]
on 1 
FROM [Adventure Works]

[image]

Edit:Changes based on comment

with member measures.t 
as

str(datepart("YYYY",Now()))+"12"
//DateAdd("m",-2,Now())
//)

select 
{measures.t }
on columns,

[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2014]
on rows
from 
[Adventure Works]

Result

[image]

Comment: Neither I am not using any hierarchy nor I want any calculation like sales,amount,or anything else with that.On the basis of current date time I want last month

Comment: @vishalpundir that was an example of how to do it if you are using a userhierarchy. Comming back to the question, so you want the last month of current year which will always be december. So for today the result should be 201912 ?